How to handle multiple/overlapping values in case statements
I have two different combination of values in my table.

New, Change request, Cancellation
Renewal, Change request, Cancellation .

For the first combination, I need to mark status as yes
For the second one, need to mark status as No
Note:Both combinations would available for same Id and timestamp
Case when date= min(date) over (partition by id, date) and abc. status in ('New', Change request', 'Cancellation') then 'Y' 
when date= min(date) over (partition by id, date) and abc. status in ('Renewal', Change request', 'Cancellation') then 'N' 
Else 'unknown' end as status_indicator
From table_name abc


Not sure if this figures in, however, you are missing a string quote after 'New'

Without some sample data and expected result - it is impossible to tell what to do.
There are something that you should have in mind when dealing with Case expresions and with analytic functions, though.
To explain it, here are some sample data (a blind guess) to work with:
--      S a m p l e    D a t a :
Create Table table_name ( id Number(6), a_date Date, status Varchar2(32) );

INSERT INTO table_name
( Select 1, DATE '2024-10-21', 'New'     UNION ALL 
  Select 1, DATE '2024-10-23', 'Renewal' UNION ALL 

  Select 2, DATE '2024-10-22', 'New'     UNION ALL 
  Select 2, DATE '2024-10-22', 'Renewal' UNION ALL
  
  Select 3, DATE '2024-10-29', 'Renewal' UNION ALL 
  Select 3, DATE '2024-10-31', 'New'     UNION ALL
  
  Select 4, DATE '2024-10-25', 'New'     UNION ALL 

  Select 5, DATE '2024-10-27', 'Renewal' 
);


Case expression is sequential - the first condition satisfied returns the value and exits Case - all remaining conditions are omited
Your Partition By clause in Min() Over() analytic function gets to evaluate row by row (id, a_date combo is most likely unique with status column making the difference)


this makes your Case expression overcoded ...

Select  abc.id, abc.a_date, abc.status, 
        Case    When abc.a_date = Min(abc.a_date) Over(Partition By abc.id, abc.a_date) And 
                     abc.status IN('New', 'Change request', 'Cancellation') Then 'Y' 
                When abc.a_date= Min(abc.a_date) Over(Partition By abc.id, abc.a_date) And 
                     abc.status IN('Renewal', 'Change request', 'Cancellation') Then 'N' 
        Else   'unknown' 
        End     as status_indicator
From    table_name abc

... the same result could be fetched using just status column ...
Select  abc.id, abc.a_date, abc.status, 
        Case    When abc.status = 'New' Then 'Y' 
                When abc.status = 'Renewal' Then 'N'
        Else   'unknown' 
        End     as status_indicator
From    table_name abc

... Result is the same for both



ID
A_DATE
STATUS
STATUS_INDICATOR




1
21-OCT-24
New
Y


1
23-OCT-24
Renewal
N


2
22-OCT-24
New
Y


2
22-OCT-24
Renewal
N


3
29-OCT-24
Renewal
N


3
31-OCT-24
New
Y


4
25-OCT-24
New
Y


5
27-OCT-24
Renewal
N



For analytic function using Min(a_date) Over() to make some distinction you should change Partition By clause like here (just as an example - not the solution cause we don't know your data)
Select  abc.id, abc.a_date, abc.status, 
        Case 
                When abc.a_date = Min(abc.a_date) Over(Partition By abc.id) And 
                     abc.status IN('New', 'Change request', 'Cancellation') Then 'Y' 
                When a_date= Min(a_date) Over(Partition By abc.id) And 
                     abc.status IN('Renewal', 'Change request', 'Cancellation') Then 'N' 
        Else   'unknown' 
        End     as status_indicator
From    table_name abc

R e s u l t :



ID
A_DATE
STATUS
STATUS_INDICATOR




1
21-OCT-24
New
Y


1
23-OCT-24
Renewal
unknown


2
22-OCT-24
New
Y


2
22-OCT-24
Renewal
N


3
29-OCT-24
Renewal
N


3
31-OCT-24
New
unknown


4
25-OCT-24
New
Y


5
27-OCT-24
Renewal
N



fiddle
